# Simple C++ GPA Calculator Problems

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm trying to create a GPA calculator by using a GradePoint() function to do the actual conversion and the int main() to be for cin and cout.

I have been stuck for hours. I have tried many different things and looked up lots of different tutorials but nothing seems to be simmilar to what i need to do.

**GradePoint() function requirements are as follows.**

This function will result in one of two outcomes. If the parameter is between 0 and 100, the function will round off the grade to the nearest whole number and return the equivalent GPA value. Otherwise, if the grade coming in is not between 0 and 100, the function will throw a std::out_of_range exception.

**int main() requirements are as follows.**

Prompt user to enter a grade and make sure it is numeric. Do not validate range because this will be done in the GradePoint() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

//function prototypes 
double GradePoint(double p);

// testing some funtions

int main()
{
    double p = 0.0; 

    cout << "Please a percentage grade to convert to grade points: "; 
    cin >> p; 

    while(!(cin >> p))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cout << "Please enter a numeric value: ";
    }

    cout << "A percentage grade of " << p; 
    cout << " Is a grade point average of " << GradePoint;

    return 0;

}

double GradePoint(double p)
{
    double g;
    if (p >=90 && p <=100)
        g = 5.0;
    else if (p >=85 && p <=89)
        g = 4.5;
    else if (p >=80 && p <=84)
        g = 4.0; 
    else if (p >=75 && p <=79)
        g = 3.5;
    else if(p >=70 && p <=74)
        g = 3.0; 
    else if (p >=65 && p <=69)
        g = 2.5;
    else if (p >=60 && p <=64)
        g = 2.0; 
    else if (p >=55 && p <=59)
        g = 1.5; 
    else if (p >=50 && p <=54)
        g = 1.0;
    else if (p <50)
        g = 0.0;
    return g; 
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  What issue are you having?

Comment: `cin.sync();` should be `cin.ignore();`. Also, `GradePoint` doesn't call a function.

Comment: There are values which are not covered in `GradePoint()` e.g. 89 < p < 90. If those fractions may not appear, you might consider to re-think your types. (`int` instead of `double` could be the better choice.) Otherwise, you have to re-think the design of your `GradePoint()` function.

Comment: Use  `cout << " Is a grade point average of " << GradePoint(p); ` (with the parameter `p` passed in the brackets).

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what i needed!! Cant believe i over looked this for hours.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

First off the code in GradePoint could be a whole lot cleaner. A grade point average is roughly PERCENTAGE / 20, and using and using math.h show here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/ you can round the percentages to the nearest percent.

```
double GradePoint(double p){

double g;

g = round(p) / 20;

return g;

}
```

Next off, when compiling your code, it does not seem to work unless you pass in p to the grade point parameters.

```
    cout << " Is a grade point average of " << GradePoint(p);
```